# Get a certain amount of characters between 2 strings in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser and it works pretty fine. In the page which I'm trying to parse I have the following in a JavaScript function:

```
listCounter.addItem(13981, 'timer_31486');
```

And I actually need to take "13981" from that string. What I want to do is - find "timer_31486" in the HTML content I get from the parser and take a certain amount of symbols before that string. However I'm not sure how that can be achieved.

Could anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) could help here, I guess.

Comment: Thanks. Any hint of which exactly?

Comment: Not out of my head. How about trying to [experiment on your own](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/)?

Comment: try: preg_match( "/\((\d+), 'timer_\d+'\)/", $htmlString, $matches ); check for the correct entry in $matches

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should probably use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) if the length is always the same.
If not, just use str_replace and scrap what you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, but I'm not sure how the replacement can work here. I have a bunch of HTML code and I want to find "timer_31486" there and then take the number which stands before it. Say, find the position of "timer_31486" in HTML and take 10 characters which stand before that string. That's what I need to do.